# What is this for loop with a colon?

Tags: java

I am reading an example in my textbook (finding the path of a file recursively) and came across this format for a loop

```
for (File folderItem : dir.listFiles()){}
```

The only for loop I'm used to is

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){}
```

How does this loop work, and what is the logic behind it?

Answer (score -1):

This is a new type of for loop (introduced in Java 5). It is used to iterate over some types of collections. It's basically identical to

```
File[] files = dir.listFiles();
for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
{
    File folderItem = files[i];
    // Code
}
```

Comment: Actually it was introduced in Java 5.

Comment: Released 12 years ago.

Comment: Not really new. It came out with Java 5, in 2004. (also it is a little more complicated than that. It is closer to an iterator loop.)